# Shemona Veshishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred sixty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

168 years passed between the two wars that the Jewish People fought against a Yavin king of Chatzor. The first was in Yehoshua's times (Josh. ch. 10), in the year 2488; the second was Devorah and Barak's battle (Jud. chs. 4-5 - last week's haftarah), in 2656.

(Incidentally, both of these battles also featured Hashem orchestrating supernatural celestial displays: the hailstones, and the sun standing still, the first time around; and "the stars in their courses" fighting against the Canaanite army the second time.)

Comment: Source for the years, please?

Comment: Seder Olam Rabbah places the first battle (and the stopping of the sun) within three months of the entry into Eretz Yisrael, on 3 Tammuz (http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34250&pgnum=52). After that, it goes on to say (http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34250&pgnum=54 and following page), we have 28 years of Yehoshua's leadership, 40 of Osniel ben Kenaz (including eight years of subjugation to Aram), 80 of Ehud ben Gera (including 18 years of subjugation to Moav), and 20 years of Yavin's subjugation of the Jewish People before Devorah and Barak beat him. 28+40+80+20=168.

Answer (score 5):

In the Tur Yoreh Deah, [Siman 168](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4914) is missing.

See also: [What happened to Siman 168?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47997/what-happened-to-siman-168)

(I saw Double AA's comment there, and gave Shmuel Brin a whole day to come post this, but he never did, even though i saw that he logged on since then...)

Answer (score 3):

A week has 168 hours. 7 x 24 = 168

The world was created in one week.

Answer (score 3):

Parshas Pinchas has 168 pesukim.

Answer (score 2):

Yitzchok was 168 years old when Yosef was sold to Mitzrayim.

Yaakov was 91 when Yosef was born, Yitzchok was 151 when Yosef was born. 151 + 17 = 168

Answer (score 2):

There are 168 sins for which the primary punishment is lashes. Source: [*Rambam*, *Sanhedrin* 19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e119n.htm).