# Shemona Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Megila 15: Rami bar Abba says that Haman had 208 children as the Posuk says ורוב בניו and V'rov = 208. The Gemara questions that the Gematria of V'rov is 214. R' Nachman bar Yitzchok answers ורב כתיב.

Comment: Seasonality FTW.

Comment: See also: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6571/arbaa-asar-umatayim-mi-yodeya/6573#6573

Answer (score 2):

On Shabbos Parshas Beshalach we read the "Song at the Sea" from the Torah, and Devorah's song as the haftarah. These songs were composed 208 years apart.

(The battle against Sisera was [168 years](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5293/shemona-veshishim-umeya-mi-yodeya/5304#5304) after the Jews entered Eretz Yisrael. Add 40 for the number of years from the Exodus until then.)

Answer (score 0):

Yitzchak = 208

Rivka = 307

208 + 307 = 515 = Tefila